# Extra Parameters in Parameter File - Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 1 parameter file for each environment. Let's call it :

dev.json

test.json

Each one of these files have parameters needed by other templates file:

ex: Dev environment has multiple templates such as:

Lambda.yaml

SNS.yaml

All parameters for these files come from dev.json file.

Question: How do I make parameters optional in parameter file so that if it is not needed in lambda.yaml then it will be ignored.
I am getting errors such as [parameters] do not exists in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a default value for your parameters.

```yaml
# File: template.yml
parameters:
- name: environmentFile
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
 - script: echo ${{ parameters.environmentFile }}
```

This way you can consume your template without passing any value to its parameters.

```yaml
# File: template-caller.yml
extends:
  template: simple-param.yml
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is if dev.json has 2 parameters and only 1 is used by lambda.yaml file , then how do I ignore the other one in lambda.yaml file. Are you saying to keep the second parameter in lambda.yaml file with default value empty ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.